# Eclipse on Windows: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: MainMethod : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been trying to fix this problem for several hours now, and I am totally at my wits end.

My old computer crashed, but luckily I was able to recover most of my files. I installed eclipse on my desktop, and attempted to import a few projects into eclipse. Every one of them had problems, and not a single one will run. I am running Windows 7 on a homebuild PC- I am 99% sure this is not a hardware problem, I don't think you need specs.

First, every time I import I have followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422683/eclipse-not-recognizing-strings-and-classes) because it is the first of my problems: every time I import a project, eclipse will not recognize anything from java and I apparently need to manually tell it what to use (which is annoying, and if anyone has a fix for this it would be great to know how to stop it).

But the big problem comes after I fix that. Whenever I try to run the project, no matter which project it is I get the error I copied in the description:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: MainMethod : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried just about everything, and am getting pretty close to just breaking the whole thing. I have followed all of the following guides: [this one](http://crunchify.com/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-comcrunchifymain-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0/), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624038/peculiar-eclipse-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor) and [this one](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/943101/). All of them say to do the same thing: change the project preferences and check the compiler settings. The settings should match.

I am running JDK7 and JRE7. JRE8/JDK8 is not installed anywhere on my desktop- I am not sure why eclipse seems to think it is. My question is this: how do I fix this problem? Do I need to do a clean install and follow a specific set of steps to stop this from happening? Do I need to put JDK8 on my computer? Do I need ro re-import the projects into the workspace in a specific way? Am I just stuck?

Comment: You have Java 8 installed *somewhere*.

Comment: Maybe your project was created in JDK8 but now you want to run it in JDK7?

Comment: Who's compiling your class files? Eclipse, or something externally, because  `MainMethod` has been compiled with Java 8 in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed the steps of configuring JDK, the project might be referring to previously generated classes. You may try `Project` on menu > `Clean`, select all projects and then try to run the application.

Moreover, go to Project Properties, `Java Build Path`, `Libraries` and confirm that you are referring to the correct `Java Runtime` version.

Answer (score 0):

Your project was created with a version of Java JDK, but your eclipse has a older version of JDK.

Verify if the version of your project's JDK is the same of the eclipse's JDK.